# Trying to get page to scroll

Tags: html, css

having a heck of a time getting this correct, how do I get this to scroll down, have tried different things from here and online but nothing is working can someone please lend a hand?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

  <link href="https://www.carymcclure.com/public_html/favicon.ico?v=1" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />

  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">

  <style>
    body {
      width: 40%;
      background-image: url("../img/ivyt.gif");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Ivy Tech Transcripts</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="../css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Get what to scroll down?  You don't have an open `<body>` tag and there is no content present...

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: alexander, the entire page

Comment: Please provide more, what you want, to be honest I don't understand what do you want to do

Comment: the problem i am having is that the picture is longer than what is showing I need the page to be able to scroll down so that they can see the whole file (it is a picture of transcripts.

Comment: I would recommend the following: **1)** Create a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) that illustrates the problem (a [mcve])-- use an image hosted on imgur that works to reproduce the issue **2)** Explain the steps to reproduce, the expected behavior, and the actual behavior.  This will be sufficient to allow the community to understand the issue and assist.  As it currently is there is insufficient info for anyone to provide an answer with any confidence it will help your specific case.

Comment: @chefcj do you have a copy of the image you can attach here?

Comment: alexander, i added the snippet but not sure how to do anything with it

Comment: Shania, not sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
      
  <link href="https://www.carymcclure.com/public_html/favicon.ico?v=1" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
          
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
     
  <style>
      
 body {
    width:40%;
    background-image: url("../img/ivyt.gif");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;           
      }
 </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Welcome to Cary McClures' Portfolio</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add some contexte / explanation with your code please.

Answer (score 0):

A background-image is used as background for the available space. You can load your image as `<img src="../img/ivyt.gif">` or you have to add width and height properties to the element (in this case body) according to the aspect ratio of the image to provide visiblity

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <link href="https://www.carymcclure.com/public_html/favicon.ico?v=1" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
  <meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#ffffff">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Welcome to Cary McClures' Portfolio</title>
  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="../css/bootstrap-4.4.1.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <img src="../img/ivyt.gif">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so replace the:  body {
      width: 40%;
      background-image: url("../img/ivyt.gif");
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
    } with the <img src="../img/ivyt.gif">   ?

Comment: @chefcj I added the example according to your code example